# moving off a form in lynx when there is only a form element on page

Tags: lynx

In Lynx, Is there a way to get to the options or go menu when there is a single text entry box on the page ?

for example a html file containing just

`<input type="text" />`

Do i have to Control C and restart or is there another way to move on ?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> then g and o are like normal